# Difference between using FieldValue.serverTimestamp and Date.now

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any performance or functional difference between `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp` and using `Date.now()`(from a central server)?

Answer (score 7):

If you write `Date.now()` from the client into the database, you're writing the **client-side** timestamp. If on the other hand you write `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp`, it ends up writing the **server-side** timestamp.

There are a few types of changes between the two:

1. The timestamp on a client is frequently off from the actual time on the server, meaning that the two values will be different.
2. If you write the timestamp from the client, that means that a malicious user can provide their own value.
3. A client is guaranteed to have some latency in its connection to the database, which means that even on a perfectly set client, and with a perfectly friendly user, there is still going to be a difference between the values.
4. If you use server timestamp you can enforce its value in security rules. See the documentation for [`Request.time`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) for info on this.

Note that there are valid use cases for using either values. For example:

- If you want to record when the user initiated an action in their own terms, you'll want to use the client-side timestamp.
- If you want to record when some data was definitively written into the database, you'll want to use the server-side timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frank. So if I set `Date.now()` from a server (not client) then would both work similarly (not same values wise but good/bad points wise)? No special advantage of how `FieldValue.serverTimestamp` stores the timestamp, right?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "special", which I don't know. But for example: the server timestamp is also propagated to the server-side security rules, which your server-side timestamp may not be.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! Can you please elaborate on what exactly does "propagate" mean in your example? Is it about being able to access that timestamp value in security rules?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time